# alphabetizing contents of array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uiimage, coverflow

I have an app in which I add UIImages to a file in the documents directory.  Each time an image is added it is named by adding 10 to the previous images name and converted to a text.

```
//this is how I change the name of the file to save it 


NSString *string2 = self.imageNameTextField.text;

int n = [string2 intValue];
int value = n + 10;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
[self.imageNameTextField setText:string];
```

Then I gather these files from documents directory in another part of an app in an array and display them in a coverflow.

```
//here I get the place in the documents directory where I saved the images along with other associated files
NSString *extension = @"jpg";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *slash2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"];
NSString *documentsDirectory13 = [slash2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.user.text];
NSString *documentsDirectory14 = [documentsDirectory13 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Family"];
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory14 error:&error];
NSMutableArray *jpegFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [contents count]];

NSLog(@"jpegFiles;%@",jpegFiles );

NSIndexSet *cafFileNameIndexes = [contents indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *fileName, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension];
}];
NSArray *cafFileNames = [contents objectsAtIndexes:cafFileNameIndexes];
NSLog(@"user;%@",self.user);

NSLog(@"cafFilesNames;%@",cafFileNames );
//here I can alphabetize the files by their file names.
NSArray *sortedArray = [cafFileNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSLog(@"sortedArray;%@",sortedArray );

NSLog(@"contents;%@",contents );


imageFile = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:cafFileNames];

//Here you get the only the .jpg files at this directory and load them as UIImages not file names.  So they have very different identifiers.
NSString *filename;
for (filename in contents)
{
    if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension])
    {
        
        [jpegFiles addObject: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory14 stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]]];
    }
}    NSLog(@"filename;%@",filename);

NSLog(@"jpegFile%@",jpegFiles);
NSLog(@"jpegFiles.count%lu",(unsigned long)jpegFiles.count );

NSLog(@"jpegFile%@",jpegFiles);

//HERE I SET A PARAMETER OF NUMBER OF IMAGES

if (cafFileNames.count<= 50) {
    
    
//THEN I START GOING THOUGH EVER NUMBER I WISH I COULD FIND A WAY
//NOT TO DO THIS BUT DO IT UNIVERSALLY
    
    if (cafFileNames.count == 0) {
        
    }
    else if (cafFileNames.count == 1) {
        NSString *nameOne = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    else if (cafFileNames.count == 2) {
        NSString *nameOne = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
        }
    else if (cafFileNames.count == 3) {
        NSString *nameOne = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThree =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:2];
        }
    else if (cafFileNames.count == 4) {
        NSString *nameOne = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThree =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *nameFour =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:3];
        }
    else if (cafFileNames.count == 5) {
        NSString *nameOne = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThree =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *nameFour =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *nameFive =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:4];
        
    }

//SINCE I HAD SIX IMAGES ALREADY I USED THIS FOR PRACTICE

    else if (cafFileNames.count == 6) {
//FIRST I SET STRINGS FOR EVERY FILE NAME IN THE ARRAY THAT HASN'T BEEN ALPHABETIZED

        NSString *nameOnea = [cafFileNames objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwoa =[cafFileNames objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThreea =[cafFileNames objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *nameFoura =[cafFileNames objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *nameFivea =[cafFileNames objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString *nameSixa =[cafFileNames objectAtIndex:5];
//THEN I SET A STRING FOR EVERY UNIQUE IDENTIFIER THAT IS IN THE SAME ORDER AS THE UNALPHABETIZED ARRAY.
        NSString *nameOneb = [jpegFiles objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwob =[jpegFiles objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThreeb =[jpegFiles objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *nameFourb =[jpegFiles objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *nameFiveb =[jpegFiles objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString *nameSixb =[jpegFiles objectAtIndex:5];

 //THEN I SET A STRING FOR THE ALPHABETIZED ARRAY.
        NSString *nameOnec = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwoc =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThreec =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *nameFourc =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *nameFivec =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString *nameSixc =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:5];
        NSLog(@"nameOnea%@",nameOnea);
        NSLog(@"nameTwoa%@",nameTwoa);
        NSLog(@"nameThreea%@",nameThreea);
        NSLog(@"nameFoura%@",nameFoura);
        NSLog(@"nameFivea%@",nameFivea);
        NSLog(@"nameSixa%@",nameSixa);
        NSLog(@"nameOneb%@",nameOneb);
        NSLog(@"nameTwob%@",nameTwob);
        NSLog(@"nameThreeb%@",nameThreeb);
        NSLog(@"nameFourb%@",nameFourb);
        NSLog(@"nameFiveb%@",nameFiveb);
        NSLog(@"nameSixb%@",nameSixb);
        NSLog(@"nameOnec%@",nameOnec);
        NSLog(@"nameTwoc%@",nameTwoc);
        NSLog(@"nameThreec%@",nameThreec);
        NSLog(@"nameFourc%@",nameFourc);
        NSLog(@"nameFivec%@",nameFivec);
        NSLog(@"nameSixc%@",nameSixc);

//THEN I COMPARE THE UNALPHABETIZED ARRAY NAMES WITH THE     ALPHABETIZED ARRAY NAMES AND WHERE THEY MATCH I SET THE    CORRESPONDING UNIQUE IDENTIFIER TO A STRING FOR FIRST PLACE,   SECOND PLACE, ETC.
        
        if ([nameOnec isEqualToString:nameOnea]) {one = nameOneb;NSLog(@"one%@",one);}
        else if ([nameOnec isEqualToString:nameTwoa]) {one = nameTwob;NSLog(@"one%@",one);}
        else if ([nameOnec isEqualToString:nameThreea]) {one = nameThreeb;NSLog(@"one%@",one);}
        else if ([nameOnec isEqualToString:nameFoura]) {one = nameFourb;NSLog(@"one%@",one);}
        else if ([nameOnec isEqualToString:nameFivea]) {one = nameFiveb;NSLog(@"one%@",one);}
        else if ([nameOnec isEqualToString:nameSixa]) {one = nameSixb;NSLog(@"one%@",one);}
        
        if ([nameTwoc isEqualToString:nameOnea]) {two = nameOneb;NSLog(@"two%@",two);}
        else if ([nameTwoc isEqualToString:nameTwoa]) {two = nameTwob;NSLog(@"two%@",two);}
        else if ([nameTwoc isEqualToString:nameThreea]) {two = nameThreeb;NSLog(@"two%@",two);}
        else if ([nameTwoc isEqualToString:nameFoura]) {two = nameFourb;NSLog(@"two%@",two);}
        else if ([nameTwoc isEqualToString:nameFivea]) {two = nameFiveb;NSLog(@"two%@",two);}
        else if ([nameTwoc isEqualToString:nameSixa]) {two = nameSixb;NSLog(@"two%@",two);}
        if ([nameThreec isEqualToString:nameOnea]) {three = nameOneb;NSLog(@"three%@",three);}
        else if ([nameThreec isEqualToString:nameTwoa]) {three = nameTwob;NSLog(@"three%@",three);}
        else if ([nameThreec isEqualToString:nameThreea]) {three = nameThreeb;NSLog(@"three%@",three);}
        else if ([nameThreec isEqualToString:nameFoura]) {three = nameFourb;NSLog(@"three%@",three);}
        else if ([nameThreec isEqualToString:nameFivea]) {three = nameFiveb;NSLog(@"three%@",three);}
        else if ([nameThreec isEqualToString:nameSixa]) {three = nameSixb;NSLog(@"three%@",three);}
        if ([nameFourc isEqualToString:nameOnea]) {four = nameOneb;NSLog(@"four%@",four);}
        else if ([nameFourc isEqualToString:nameTwoa]) {four = nameTwob;NSLog(@"four%@",four);}
        else if ([nameFourc isEqualToString:nameThreea]) {four = nameThreeb;NSLog(@"four%@",four);}
        else if ([nameFourc isEqualToString:nameFoura]) {four = nameFourb;NSLog(@"four%@",four);}
        else if ([nameFourc isEqualToString:nameFivea]) {four = nameFiveb;NSLog(@"four%@",four);}
        else if ([nameFourc isEqualToString:nameSixa]) {four = nameSixb;NSLog(@"four%@",four);}
        if ([nameFivec isEqualToString:nameOnea]) {five = nameOneb;NSLog(@"five%@",five);}
        else if ([nameFivec isEqualToString:nameTwoa]) {five = nameTwob;NSLog(@"five%@",five);}
        else if ([nameFivec isEqualToString:nameThreea]) {five = nameThreeb;NSLog(@"five%@",five);}
        else if ([nameFivec isEqualToString:nameFoura]) {five = nameFourb;NSLog(@"five%@",five);}
        else if ([nameFivec isEqualToString:nameFivea]) {five = nameFiveb;NSLog(@"five%@",five);}
        else if ([nameFivec isEqualToString:nameSixa]) {five = nameSixb;NSLog(@"five%@",five);}
        if ([nameSixc isEqualToString:nameOnea]) {six = nameOneb;NSLog(@"six%@",six);}
        else if ([nameSixc isEqualToString:nameTwoa]) {six = nameTwob;NSLog(@"six%@",six);}
        else if ([nameSixc isEqualToString:nameThreea]) {six  = nameThreeb;NSLog(@"six%@",six);}
        else if ([nameSixc isEqualToString:nameFoura]) {six  = nameFourb;NSLog(@"six%@",six);}
        else if ([nameSixc isEqualToString:nameFivea]) {six  = nameFiveb;NSLog(@"six%@",six);}
        else if ([nameSixc isEqualToString:nameSixa]) {six  = nameSixb;NSLog(@"six%@",six);}
        }
    else if (cafFileNames.count == 7) {
        NSString *nameOne = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *nameThree =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *nameFour =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *nameFive =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString *nameSix =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:5];
        NSString *nameSeven =[sortedArray objectAtIndex:6];
        
    }}
//FINALLY I PUT THE ASSOCIATED FILES IN THE COVERFLOW ARRAY.

covers = [NSMutableArray     arrayWithObjects:one,two,three,four,five,six,nil];
/*covers= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jpegFiles];{
    for (filename in jpegFiles);
}*/
NSLog(@"covers%@", covers);
NSLog(@"covers%@", covers);



// Add the coverflow view

coverflow.coverflowDelegate = self;
coverflow.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:coverflow];
[coverflow setNumberOfCovers:(int)jpegFiles.count ];
```

LIKE I SAID THIS WORKS BUT IT WILL BE A PAIN TO WRITE THIS FOR COUNTS FROM 0-100 OR MORE.  SO IF ANYONE CAN HELP ME DO THIS PROCESS MORE EFFICIENTLY I'D BE VERY GREATFUL.

Comment: You could just keep a list of file urls instead of the actual image data. Then you could sort the urls (based on the last path component for example) and load the images when needed.

Comment: I have figured out a way.  I have edited my original post to show my process.  The only problem I would have to do the same thing for every count of the images.  If someone can help me figure out a way to do this without having to go through every count I would really appreciate it.